# Business plan template

Tags: finance

i have to do a business plan as an assignment in my computer science engineering school. I'm looking for help .. can anyone provides me with a complete template ? or an example to follow

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many online. I don't recommend any of them, unless you're looking for a structure to guide you through. Business plans must suit the idea, and not otherwise.

You can find generic templates out there, but I believe they should work as a guidelines - i.e., things you should include. But the point of a business plan is to explain everything about an idea/project and explore the outcomes from there. If you are able to explain every single detail of your idea, you'll find some weaknesses - which you must include, of course - and your exercise is now to think about how can you over come those weaknesses.

Some questions for you to consider:

- Who are you? Why are you proceeding with this idea?
- What is the idea? What is the product? Why is it so different?
- Where are you/your firm located? Why? Any particular reason? Where should it be located if you could?
- What is your market? Age, type, profession, gender, etc etc
- How do you expect to reach out to those people about the idea? After that, how do you want them to buy your product/service?
- (At this point, you can perform the so-well-known SWOT analysis and other similar matrices (BCG matrix, for instance).
- How are you going to finance yourself? Why? Why or why not loans, business angels, credit, etc etc ? What is your financial strategy? How are you going to manage the (few) cash you will have?
- Are you going to invest on marketing? If so, how, why, why not?
- Okay, you go some sales. What are you going to do with the cash you just earned? Why? For how long are you keeping that strategy
- How are things going to unfold once you get it running? Why? Why not in a totally different way?

There are no identical business plans. You have to adequate yours to your idea. A quick example: When there is a physical product, you *must* include the design, explain it, whys and why not. When there is a service, for instance, perhaps it is better to explain why is it different than other solutions (you know, reinventing the wheel, not inventing it).

I hope these will help you work something around.